# avoid this.state and this.props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I started to learn reactjs and I find rewriting this.state and this.props each time is very annoying.
I tried to create 2 variables in the render function like so :
`let state = this.state;`
`let props = this.props;`
to write state instead of this.state and props instead of this.props but isn't there any way to do it in the entire component?

Comment: Does it really make that huge difference? `this.props` vs `props`?

Comment: I was just looking for a way to make the code more readable

Comment: You should probably look at props destructuring.

Comment: No, there isn't any good way to do it for the entire component. It is common practice to [destructure props in react](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0) if the properties are frequently used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take advantage of destructuring-assigments.

May be you have a constructor in component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {color: 'green'};
}
```

and if you want to access it you have to write:

```
<div>Color here:{this.state.color}</div>
```

And say in a component, you may have multiple state variable. So you want to get rid of write this.state.variableName for repeated times.'

So you can destructure it:

```
const {variableName1, variableName2} = this.state;
```

So when you need to access it, just write it:

```
<div>{variableName1}</div>
```

So you may get rid of write full `{this.state.variableName1}`

```
const variableName1 = this.state.variableName1
const variableName2 = this.state.variableName2
```

so you may write less code by destructure it:

```
const {variableName1, variableName2} = this.state;
```

and for props also the same format.

Comment: where would you add the destructure line? In the constructor or in all functions where you need it? If latter, then wouldn't that not add more boilerplate overhead?

Comment: @Se7enDays, Not in the constructor but  in the other methods where you need it. Since we can put code in the JSX. so whenever you need just destructure it according to your requirements so that you can avoid more verbose.  In constructor, we will just initialize it.